# How can coverage have a coverpoint for 'x' in the systemverilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to get a bin for the value of 'x' in the SystemVerilog as shown below, since the logic has 4 types of 0,1,x,z, I want to check the coverpoint as a bin, so I made a simple example to check the value of 4 types in the coverpoint.

```
typedef enum logic [2:0] { A,B,C,D } alpha;
program main;    
alpha y;         
alpha values[$]= '{A,B,C};
                 
covergroup cg;   
  option.per_instance = 1;
cover_point_y : coverpoint y;
endgroup         
                 
covergroup bidir_coverage;

  option.per_instance = 1;
bidir_coverage_y :  coverpoint y {
    bins low = {0};
    bins high = {1};
    bins x_state = { 'bx };
  }              
endgroup         
                 
                 
                 
                 
cg cg_inst = new();
bidir_coverage bidir_coverage_inst = new();
                 
initial          
foreach(values[i])
begin            
y = values[i];   
cg_inst.sample();
bidir_coverage_inst.sample();
end              
                 
endprogram
```

Problem is that '`x_state`' is not created as a bin. How can coverage have a coverpoint for 'x' in the systemverilog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the use of an enumerated type without declaring 'x as a valid state for that `enum`. You would need to write something like

```
typedef enum logic [2:0] { X='x, A=0,B,C,D} alpha;
module main;    
  alpha y;         
  alpha values[$]= '{A,B,C};
                 
  covergroup cg;   
    option.per_instance = 1;
    cover_point_y : coverpoint y;
  endgroup         
                   
  covergroup bidir_coverage;
    option.per_instance = 1;
    bidir_coverage_y :  coverpoint y {
      bins low = {0};
      bins high = {1};
      bins x_state = { X };  // or 3'bx
    }            
  endgroup       
                 
  cg cg_inst = new();
  bidir_coverage bidir_coverage_inst = new();
                 
  initial          
    foreach(values[i])
      begin            
        y = values[i];   
        cg_inst.sample();
        bidir_coverage_inst.sample();
      end              
                 
endmodule
```

Note that automatically created bins in coverpoint_y never include X or Z states

Answer (score 0):

1. By default, a value or transition bin definition can specify 4-state values. When a bin definition includes an `X` or `Z`, it indicates that the bin count should only be incremented when the sampled value has an `X` or `Z` in the same bit positions, i.e., the comparison is done using `===`.
2. A wildcard bin definition causes all `X`, `Z`, or `?` to be treated as wildcards for `0` or `1`. That is, A wildcard bin definition only considers 2-state values; sampled values containing `X` or `Z` are excluded. (see *SystemVerilog IEEE Std 1800-2017* **19.5.4**)
3. Automatically created bins only consider 2-state values; sampled values containing `X` or `Z` are excluded. (see *SystemVerilog IEEE Std 1800-2017* **19.5.3**)

So in theory your requirement is easy to achieve, as you did, but the issue is that empty bins are excluded from coverage actually (see *SystemVerilog IEEE Std 1800-2017* **19.11.1**):

> **If there is no value or transition associated with a bin, the bin is ignored and shall not contribute to the coverage computation;** that is, the bin is excluded from both the numerator and the denominator of the coverage equation.

Of course, your simulator may also give the following warning:

> **Warning**: (vsim-8549) After **dropping the illegal, ignore or invalid values**, the values list associated with scalar bin `x_state` in Coverpoint `bidir_coverage_y` of Covergroup instance `bidir_coverage_inst` has converged to empty list. The bin will be taken out of coverage calculation.

For example:

```
bit [1:0] a;
covergroup cg_a;
  coverpoint a {
    bins all_low = { 2'b00 };
    bins all_high = { 2'b11 };
    bins test = { 2'b01, 4, 2'bxx };
  }
endgroup
```

Since variable `a` can only have values `2'b00`, `2'b01`, `2'b10` or `2'b11`, so value `4` and `2'bxx` in the bin 'test' is invalid and will be ignored. So the actual coverage calculation looks like this:

```
bit [1:0] a;
covergroup cg_a;
  coverpoint a {
    bins all_low = { 2'b00 };
    bins all_high = { 2'b11 };
    bins test = { 2'b01 };
  }
endgroup
```

So if a bin contains only invalid values, such as `bins test = { 4, 2'bxx };`, finally the bins will be empty and excluded from coverage.